# Struts2-Menu on Jsp

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to show struts2 menu on my jsp page but it gives me errorr as follows:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: The menu repository could not be found.
```

I search on internet i found that it requires commons.lang jar, commons-logging.jar and i already have this jar in my struts2 project.

How can i show struts2 menu on my jsp page?
 My jsp code as follows:

```
<menu:useMenuDisplayer name="TabbedMenu" config="/templates/tabs.html">
        <ul id="primary-nav" >
                <li class="pad">&nbsp;</li>
                    <menu:displayMenu name="Order"/>
                    <menu:displayMenu name="Report"/>
                    <menu:displayMenu name="BatchProcessing"/>
                    <menu:displayMenu name="Master"/>
        </ul>
</menu:useMenuDisplayer>
```

I have menu-config.xml as follows:

```
<MenuConfig>
<Displayers>
        <Displayer name="TabbedMenu"  type="net.sf.navigator.displayer.TabbedMenuDisplayer"/>
    </Displayers>
    <Menus>
        <Menu name="Order" title="Order" />
        <Menu name="Report" title="Report" />
        <Menu name="BatchProcessing" title="Batch Processing" />
        <Menu name="Master" title="Master" />
    </Menus>
</MenuConfig>
```

Comment: u might b missing some jar files. please check

Comment: I have struts-menu-2.4.3.jar, velocity-1.4.jar and velocity-tools-1.0.jar and all other jars required for struts application. Is there any other jar required?

Comment: see here http://sourceforge.net/projects/struts-menu/forums/forum/160189/topic/765727

Comment: Have you considered using Apache Tiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add **commons-logging.jar**  and **commons-lang.jar** in your project at **WEB-INF/Lib**

Comment: actually i forgot to write MenuContextListener  in my web.xml and there is one more jar required standard 1.0.6 for my project